# Android GLES20 - how do I reduce the overhead involved in rendering into two sequential framebuffers before rendering into screen?

Tags: android, opengl-es

Let's say I have a rendering pipeline that involves rendering a frame from a video into FBO A with Fragment Shader A, then rendering from FBO A to FBO B with Fragment Shader B, and finally rendering the texture in FBO B into the screen with Fragment Shader C.

This pipeline doesn't seem to have any lag in higher end devices like a Galaxy S6, but when I tested it in a Huawei P8 Lite (I think it's a low-end or mid-end device), for some reason there was significant overhead, so that each frame takes around 0.33 seconds to be rendered on-screen.

Which steps should I take to alleviate this overhead in low-end or mid-end devices? Or should I just ditch this method altogether and go with Fragment Shader Stitching?

EDIT: This is basically what's in my `onDrawFrame` call:

```
private void drawActual() {

    if(currentSEFilterPosition != storedSEFilterPosition || changeFragmentShader)
    {
        /*
         The code for switching filters on the fly is here
         */
    } else {
        GLES20.glDisable(GLES20.GL_BLEND);
    }

    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    drawBeautyCamera();
    long bCamera = (System.currentTimeMillis() - start);
    drawToFBO();
    long fbo = (System.currentTimeMillis() - start);
    postProcessFromFBO();
    long pProcess = (System.currentTimeMillis() - start);
    Log.i("draw_durations", bCamera+" "+fbo+" "+pProcess);
}
```

Where `drawBeautyCamera()` and `drawFBO()` are basically the following code repeated twice with a different GL Program:

```
 private void drawBeautyCamera() {
    GLES20.glUseProgram(beautyCamProgram);
    checkGlError("glUseProgram");

    GLES20.glBindFramebuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, mBeautyCamFramebuffer);

    GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, mTextureID);
    checkGlError("glBindTexture");

    //Log.i("current_float_timestamp", muTimestampFloatHandle+"");
    //onPrelimPreDrawFrame();

    mTriangleVertices.position(TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_POS_OFFSET);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(maBeautycamPositionHandle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
            TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_STRIDE_BYTES, mTriangleVertices);
    checkGlError("glVertexAttribPointer maPosition");
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(maBeautycamPositionHandle);
    checkGlError("glEnableVertexAttribArray maPositionHandle");

    mTriangleVertices.position(TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_UV_OFFSET);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(maBeautycamTextureHandle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
            TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_STRIDE_BYTES, mTriangleVertices);
    checkGlError("glVertexAttribPointer maTextureHandle");
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(maBeautycamTextureHandle);
    checkGlError("glEnableVertexAttribArray maTextureHandle");

    Matrix.setIdentityM(mBeautyCamMVPMatrix, 0);
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(muBeautycamMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mBeautyCamMVPMatrix, 0);
    checkGlError("glmuMVPMatrixHandleSetting");
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(muBeautycamSTMatrixHandle, 1, false, mBeautyCamSTMatrix, 0);
    checkGlError("glmuSTMatrixHandleSetting");

    GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
    checkGlError("glDrawArrays");

    //USE DEFAULT FRAMEBUFFER THIS TIME
    GLES20.glBindFramebuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
}
```

And `postProcessFromFBO()` is the following:

```
private void postProcessFromFBO() {
    GLES20.glUseProgram(specialEffectsProgram);
    checkGlError("glUseProgram");

    GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mOffscreenTexture);
    checkGlError("glBindTexture");

    onSEPreDrawFrame();
    checkGlError("onPreDrawFrame");

    mTriangleVertices.position(TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_POS_OFFSET);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(maPositionHandle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
            TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_STRIDE_BYTES, mTriangleVertices);
    checkGlError("glVertexAttribPointer maPosition");
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(maPositionHandle);
    checkGlError("glEnableVertexAttribArray maPositionHandle");

    mTriangleVertices.position(TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_UV_OFFSET);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(maTextureHandle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
            TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_STRIDE_BYTES, mTriangleVertices);
    checkGlError("glVertexAttribPointer maTextureHandle");
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(maTextureHandle);
    checkGlError("glEnableVertexAttribArray maTextureHandle");

    Matrix.setIdentityM(mMVPMatrix, 0);
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(muMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mMVPMatrix, 0);
    checkGlError("glmuMVPMatrixHandleSetting");
    Matrix.setIdentityM(mSTMatrix, 0);
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(muSTMatrixHandle, 1, false, mSTMatrix, 0);
    checkGlError("glmuSTMatrixHandleSetting");

    GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
    checkGlError("glDrawArrays");
}
```

Comment: What you tried? where's your code? or this problem is related to your code? nothing is there

Answer (score 0):

Lower-end devices will have a smaller/slower GPU, so given the latency is fine on a high-end device it's probably OK to assume this isn't a CPU software performance issue, and you are probably just trying to do too much rendering for the GPU performance you have available.

I.e. your "overhead" is highly likely just to be GPU processing, rather than something which can be avoided. Try rendering with simpler fragment shaders, or to a lower resolution.

Comment: Do you mean reducing the size of the video I'm playing, or the `SurfaceView` I'm rendering said video to?

Comment: Never mind. The performance is certainly better in lower-end GPUs if I shrink the `SurfaceView` rendering target.